# MaxCut SDP primal in mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How could one formulate the primal SDP for MaxCut in Mathematica.

I am aware of this tutorial using the dual:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/convex-optimization/max-cut-problem.html?product=mathematica

Thank you.

Edit to add further information:

What I tried (there `LaplacianMatrix` and `e` are functions from the dual example):

```
MCSDPPrimalValueAndMinimizer[graph_?GraphQ] := 
  Module[{L = LaplacianMatrix[graph], n},
   n = Dimensions[L][[1]];
   Return[
    SemidefiniteOptimization[-Tr[1/4 L . X], 
     Join[Table[
       Tr[e[i, n] . X] == 1, {i, 1, n}], {X \[VectorGreaterEqual] 0}],
      X \[Element] Matrices[{n, n}, Reals], {"PrimalMinimumValue", 
      "PrimalMinimizer"}]];
   ];
```

However, the values it returns are pretty off even for even order complete graphs --- they should match the optimal values of their maxcuts.

Comment: Please include in your question the code that you have tried and what comments you encountered.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: xxxx, please take a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thank you bbgodfrey. Thank you Kuba --- I merged my accounts (sorry for the mess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a comment, but this looks almost correct, the main issue is that instead of

```
VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}]
```

you may want to use

```
VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", n}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ilian. Yes, that works. I am grateful.