# Simple SDP using Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, programming, complex

I would like to run the following semidefinite program
$$ \textrm{Minimize}\,\, \textrm{tr}\big({AX}\big)\\
\textrm{subject to}\,\, X \geq B_1\,, X \geq B_2\,,     $$
where $A$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are fixed $2 \times 2$ Hermitian positive-semidefinite matrices and the variable $X$ is also a $2 \times 2$ Hermitian positive-semidefinite matrix. The following is my attempt so far.

```
MinimizeProblem[A_, B1_, B2_] :=
  Return[SemidefiniteOptimization[Tr[A. X], 
    VectorGreaterEqual[{X - B1, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
     VectorGreaterEqual[{X - B2, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
     VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}], 
    X \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}, Complexes], {"PrimalMinimumValue", 
     "PrimalMinimizer"}]];
```

This returns no result, but it doesn't give me a specific error either. I suspect the problem comes from using complex matrices, as this seems to be the main way that my problem differs from other SDP examples on this site e.g. [MaxCut SDP primal in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250038/maxcut-sdp-primal-in-mathematica), but I'm not sure. In my attempts, I used the following for $A$, $B_1$ and $B_2$,
$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0.7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.3\\ \end{pmatrix}\,, \qquad B_1= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\,, \qquad  B_2= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\,.$$
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: If $A$ and $X$ are both positive semi-definite then they can be expanded in their eigenbases as $A=\sum_{i}\lambda_i|u_i \rangle\langle u_i|$ and $X=\sum_{j}\gamma_j|v_j \rangle\langle v_j|$, where every eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and $\gamma_j$ is real and non-negative. Then $\textrm{tr}\big(AX \big)=\sum_{i, j}\lambda_{i}\gamma_{j}|\langle v_j | u_i \rangle|^2$ is real and non-negative.

Comment: You seem to attempt to minimize a _complex-valued_ function. If $A$ and $X$ are complex-valued matrices, what does guarantee that $\mathrm{tr}(A X)$ is a real number? Maybe you meant to take Frobenius inner product? Then you have to apply `Re`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have edited my question to add a proof that $\textrm{tr} \big( AX\big)$ is real and non-negative if $A$ and $X$ are both positive-semidefinite.

Comment: I see. Anyways, _Mathematica_ does not _know_ about this and refuses to minimize complex-valued functions. So wrapping it with `Re` might help anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Mathematica interprets the sum `X - B1` entrywise  before doing anything at all. So for your data `X - B1` is

> {{X-1/2,X-1/2},{X-1/2,X-1/2}}

which is not what you want. In this simple case,

```
SemidefiniteOptimization[
  Tr[A . X], 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{X, B1}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{X, B2}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}], 
  X \[Element] Matrices[2, Complexes], 
  {"PrimalMinimumValue", "PrimalMinimizer"}]
```

does the job.

P.S. #1: By the way, for real data, the answer is always real.

P.S. #2: This one also runs :)

```
SemidefiniteOptimization[
  Tr[A . X], 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{X - B1, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}] && 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}], 
  X \[Element] Matrices[2, Complexes], 
  {"PrimalMinimumValue", "PrimalMinimizer"}]
```